# json_encode($array) reverse order of my php array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have `json_encode($array)` it gives me a list in a different order on google chrome

Comment: Are you sure the browser isn't ordering your output... Many modern browsers render JSON output differently.

Comment: You guys forget that in PHP `$array` can be an *associative* array. Please show the expected and actual outputs

Comment: look at the 3rd example http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

**array_reverse:** used to Return an array with elements in reverse order, e.g:

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
echo json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is done on the backend by the PHP so Google Chrome has nothing to do with this issue.

Check your array order before you encode it.

Answer (score 0):

check the value in `$array` using `var_dump` to make sure, thats the order you want.

**Edit:** look at the 3rd example in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: IE(ie9?) and chrome resort data of associative array if json encoded, not FF as im aware.

Answer (score 0):

What does your JSON data look like? If:

```
{1,2,3}
```

Your browser will not necessarily preserve the order. But if formatted as a JSON array:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Then the order will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is associative, but indexed by integers (like `$arr1 = ['3' => 'x', '2' => 'a', '1' => 'b'];`), the browser (when parsing JSON) assumes that the keys of the array indicate the order in which the values are stored (as in a classical, non-associative array - like `$arr2 = ['x','a','b'];`).

See for yourself - compare the results of parsing the JSON generated from those two associative arrays - one is indexed by non-integer strings (A), the other one is indexed by integers (even if they are string-typed in PHP) (B).

For both examples the values in PHP are stored in order: `'x', 'a', 'b'`, and only the keys are different.

**A)** associative array, **indexed by strings**

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    'foo' => 'x', 
    'bar' => 'a', 
    'baz' => 'b'
];
$json = json_encode($arr1); // $json is now a string: '{"foo":"x","bar":"a","baz":"b"}'
```

And then, in the browser:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"foo":"x","bar":"a","baz":"b"}');
console.log(jsonData); 
// prints {foo: "x", bar: "a", baz: "b"} -  the keys are in different order then expected!
```

**B)** associative array, **indexed by integers (even if they are strings in PHP!)**

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    '3' => 'x', 
    '2' => 'a', 
    '1' => 'b'
];
$json = json_encode($arr1); // $json is now a string: '"{"3":"x","2":"a","1":"b"}"'
```

And then, in the browser:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('"{"3":"x","2":"a","1":"b"}"');
console.log(jsonData); 
// prints {1: "b", 2: "a", 3: "x"} -  the keys are in different order then expected!
```

> As you see - the JSON parser assumes a classical array when the
>   indices are integers.

So if you need to maintain the order, I'd suggest switching to a classical array and perhaps adding an order / key field to the JSON (for sorting purposes - if you need it):

```
$arr1 = [
    '3' => 'x', 
    '2' => 'a', 
    '1' => 'b'
];
$json = json_encode(array_values($arr1)); // note the array_values() here - but this way you loose the index keys
```

Another way:

```
$arr1 = [
    '3' => [ 'key' => '3', 'value' => 'x'], 
    '2' => [ 'key' => '2', 'value' => 'a'],
    '1' => [ 'key' => '1', 'value' => 'b'],
];
$json = json_encode(array_values($arr1)); 
        // this way you have both values and keys, 
        // and the parsed JSON will be in the exact order you want it to be
```